# Simplified Jordan Curve Theorem for C^1 curves

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I was looking at this website:

https://people.math.osu.edu/fiedorowicz.1/math655/Jordan.html

Which had written in it that the Jordan Curve Theorem for C^1 simple closed curves was easy to prove.

I'm looking for advice on how one might go about proveing this restricted version of the theorem?

I was able to create two open sets as follows: using the fact I can create a perpendicular line from a point on the curve I could then choose a point on each side of the curve and then use open sets to create an open covering on each side of the curve.

The problem is I don't know how I would go about showing the two sets are disjoint.

Any advice would be very helpfull.

Comment: Remember that at every point on the curve there is exactly one tangent. No cusp points at all. Of course, this is only a starting reasoning.

Comment: Check the book by Guillemin and Pollack, I think, they give a simple proof in $C^1$-setting using mod 2 intersection theory. It still takes a fair amount of work to set things up.

Comment: It is pretty much a duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786984/index-of-a-jordan-curve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index of a Jordan curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786984/index-of-a-jordan-curve)