# If $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is injective, its winding number must be $\pm1$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, reference-request

Let $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be an injective continuous map, where $n\geq1$. By the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem, $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\operatorname{im}(f)$ has two components, one bounded and one unbounded. Let us denote the bounded component by $U$ and the unbounded component by $V$. Now, for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\operatorname{im}(f)$, we can consider $f$ as a map from $\mathbb{S}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{p\}$. This induces a group homomorphism between ($n$-dimensional singular) homology groups, which both happen to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I think the following is a standard result, but could not find its proof in well-known textbooks.

- If $p\in U$, the induced group homomorphism is an isomorphism (from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$).
- If $p\in V$, the induced group homomorphism is a zero map.

I could only prove the $n=1$ case ("the index of a Jordan curve must be $\pm1$"), using the Schoenflies theorem, but I believe that there must be a more natural way of explaining this. My knowledge of algebraic topology is shallow, so it would be nice to have a reference for this.

Comment: My best bet for a reference would've been Dold, but in fact, it's just an exercise in there, see IV. 7.6. Does this count as a reference then?

Comment: @Ben Thanks but I really want to see the proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is every based embedding from $S^{n}$ to $R^{n+1}\setminus\{{\bf 0}\}$ either the unit or a generator of $\pi_{n}(R^{n+1}\setminus\{{\bf 0}\})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542459/is-every-based-embedding-from-sn-to-rn1-setminus-bf-0-either-th)

Comment: @user8675309 The answer there uses smooth approximation and smooth manifold theory which I want to avoid.

Comment: Like @Ben said, this is an exercise in Dold's book, so there must be a canonical way of explaining it, without using smooth manifold theory. I don't understand why my question is closed.